# Embedding all font glyphs in an external font.swf

Tags: actionscript-3, fonts

I need access to a range of font glyphs for a localized flash application. I am using Myriad Pro which supports character sets such as Greek and others. Is it possible to embed all font glyphs by simply adding the font to the library and checking the option **Export for Actionscript**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using this guys class http://etcs.ru/blog/as3/fontloader/. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Adding the font to the library will give you access to all the available glyphs of the font. The only downside I know it is the extra weight that you add to the application, of characters that you might not use.